# Помогите Python

Tags: python

Надо после кода вырезать в любую переменную все эти числа и отсортировать их, но не через `sorted`.

```py
n = int(input("Кол-во "))
a = ''
for i in range(n):
    a = a + (input())
print(a)
```

Вырезать надо как текст, на каком то сайте видел `a[1:2]` где `a` это число, `1` и `2` это с какого по какое число включительно надо вырезать.

Пример входных данных:

```
n = 3
3
2
5
```

Вывод:

```
235
```

Comment: ничего кроме отсортировать без `sorted` не понял - надо отсортировать введенные числа? или надо введенные числа добавить в строку, потом вырезать из строки, превратить в числа и опять отсортировать?

Comment: по моему коду они вроде уже в строке, в переменной a из переменной a надо отсортировать их и вывести

Comment: вырезать числа или цифры?

Comment: вырезать числа..

Answer (score 1):

сортировка в лоб (сложность O(n^2))

```
n = int(input("Кол-во "))

arr = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

res = []

for i in range(n):
    min_value = arr[0]
    min_pos = 0

    for j in range(1, len(arr)):
        if min_value > arr[j]:
            min_pos = j
            min_value = arr[j]

    res.append(min_value)
    del arr[min_pos]

print(*res)
```

вырезать из строки числа можно так:

```
arr = list(map(int, text.split()))
```

Comment: а, еще можно без списков плс)

Comment: а с чем - сортировать в виде строки?

Comment: Ну да, в виде строки

Comment: можно уменьшить код с помощью функций `min` и `enumerate`

Comment: т.е. задача заключается в следующем: 1) ввести числа в строку 2) отсортировать числа в строке 3) не использовать стандартную сортировку 4) не использовать списки? а кортежи можно?

Comment: не знаю что такое кортежи)

Comment: @Danis, это да, я просто максимально просто и в лоб написал, но похоже нужно что-то другое :)

Comment: @user417803, вы могли бы тогда процитировать ТОЧНО в чем заключается задача

Comment: 1) надо ввести числа в строку 2) вырезать все числа 3) отсортировать их не использую стандартную сортировку, списки, и максимально просто и понятно для новичка :)

Comment: т.е. кортежи устроят? и если числа надо вырезать из строки, то где их хранить то? :)))

Comment: в отдельных переменных

Answer (score 1):

уф, у меня вот так получилось в лоб
без списков, без стандартной сортировки

```
# получить кол-во чисел
#n = int(input("Кол-во "))

# записать числа в строку
#text = ''
#for _ in range(n):
#    text += input() + ' '

# для теста
n = 5
text = '11 3435 9 323 899 '

# отсортировать числа
res = ''

for i in range(n):
    # найти минимальное число в строке
    min_value = 0
    min_pos_start = -1
    min_pos_finish = -1

    pos = 0

    while pos < len(text):
        # найти начало слова
        for pos_start in range(pos, len(text)):
            if text[pos_start] != ' ':
                break

        # найти конец слова
        for pos_finish in range(pos_start + 1, len(text)):
            if text[pos_finish] == ' ':
                break

        pos_finish = pos_finish + 1 if text[pos_finish] != ' ' else pos_finish

        # преобразовать выделенное слово в число
        try:
            value = int(text[pos_start:pos_finish])
        except:
            break

        # найти минимальное число в строке
        if value < min_value or min_pos_start == -1:
            min_pos_start = pos_start
            min_pos_finish = pos_finish
            min_value = value

        # перейти дальше по строке
        pos = pos_finish + 1


    # добавить в результат найденное число
    res += str(min_value) + ' '

    # вырезать найденное число из строки
    part1 = '' if min_pos_start == -1 else text[0:min_pos_start]
    part2 = text[min_pos_finish:]

    text = part1 + part2

# вывести результат
print(res)
```

Comment: прочитал код логику понял как и я думал только не знал как реализовать, но код слишком длинный) Тоесть найти минимальное число вставить его в отдельную переменную и так делать пока чисел не останется тем самым получится отсортированный список чисел

Comment: добавил строчку для корректной обработки одной ситуации (она в данном примере не происходит, потому что в конце каждой строки есть пробел, но если его не будет, то правка это учтет)

Comment: да, именно так и делать - как я показал в другом своем ответе - самая простая сортировка с O(n^2) сложностью - идем по строке, ищем слова, превращаем в числа, ищем минимальное, минимальное число добавляем в новую строку, а из старой вырезаем, код конечно можно улучшить и причесать немного